# Apex is not considering space as a string

Tags: apex

In the below code I wanted to print pyramid star pattern
but the apex is ignoring the space

```
String Space = ' ';//Here I have used this to give space between the stars
String Cha = '* ';//here also after star i have used a space which is also ignored
Integer n = 4;
for (Integer i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    String Pattern = '';
    for (Integer j = i; j < n; j++) {
        Pattern += Space;
    }
    for (Integer k = 1; k <= i; k++) {
        Pattern += Cha;
    }
    System.debug(Pattern);
}
```

Actual result:
After running this code in anonymous window, I am getting below pattern instead of pyramid.

```
*
**
***
****
```

expected:

```
   *
  * * 
 * * *
* * * *
```

Comment: Please check your `Space` variable. because when I copy pasted the code above it prints pyramid properly. You might have forgotten to put `' '` in your code. If there is a space then it prints the pyramid properly

Comment: I suspect it is not apex causing you issues but simply the way the text is being rendered. E.g. HTML works such that whitespace gets normalized.

Comment: @NagendraSingh thanks for the response but I used the same exact code. That is I have used ' '.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute Anonymous in the Developer Console renders logs in HTML form when using Open Log button. First, I cleaned up your code to make it easier to see the debug statement.

```
String Space = ' ';//Here I have used this to give space between the stars
String Cha = '* ';//here also after star i have used a space which is also ignored
Integer n = 4;
String[] buffer = new String[0];
for (Integer i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    String Pattern = '';
    for (Integer j = i; j < n; j++) {
        Pattern += Space;
    }
    for (Integer k = 1; k <= i; k++) {
        Pattern += Cha;
    }
    buffer.add(Pattern);
}
System.debug('\n'+String.join(buffer,'\n'));
```

Using Open Log, it'll look like this:

[image: Open Log showing Debug Statement]

But if you use the open raw log menu item, you'll get this:

```
16:20:22.1 (4551125)|USER_DEBUG|[15]|DEBUG|
   * 
  * * 
 * * * 
* * * *
```

As you can see, it renders perfectly fine.

As others have commented, it matters if the content is rendered as text or HTML. This white space collapse is default HTML behavior for most elements.

Comment: Thanks for the response now I get it